How to get the model type in Drizzle ORM?
Suppose I query the database like this:
const post = await db.query.posts.findFirst({ where: ...});

What is the type of post?
Context: I want to create a component that accepts a post like this:
type ComponentProps = {
  post: ???
}

Edit: I realized it ain't possible because the teturn type depends on the where clause so wrapping the db.query in a function f and then use ReturnType<typeof f> is probably the way to go here. Is this correct?

Figured it out.
import { posts } from "~/server/db/schema";
type Post = typeof posts.$inferSelect;


can you do that in nextjs client component?

Did you have to manually do that or does it get generated somehow?
